# Image not showing inside a Bootstrap 3 Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap for an Image Carousel.  I have 1 image inside the carousel, but the image is not showing (its size is being set to 0x0, while the Natural size is correct when using Chrome Developer Tools).

```css
.imageSection {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="imageSection">
      <div class="carousel slide" id="imageCarousel" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/r/0/O/0/X/O/image-of-person-sspeck-hi.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.  Appreciate any help regarding this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `active` to exactly one item `<div class="item active">`

From bootstraps documentation http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

> **Initial active element required** 
>   The .active class needs to be added to one of the slides. Otherwise, the carousel will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the cdn link, it seems the cdn link you are providing is broken.

Plunkr link : https://plnkr.co/edit/Tm2eXNeACc1JiMef74SA?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

<div class="imageSection">
      <div class="carousel slide" id="imageCarousel" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/r/0/O/0/X/O/image-of-person-sspeck-hi.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```